# Application.Quit() take to long to reopen the app(Unity2D)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Hi guys here is my problem(sorry for my english):

Im trying to close the game,and reopen it past 1 second.

But it take to long,5 seconds more or less in black window and then unity logo appear;

Android device monitor give me this info(yellow):

[image]

And here is my code to close the game

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {            
                PlayerPrefs.Save();
                StopAllCoroutines();
                Application.Quit();                              
    }
```

Comment: Do you have coroutines (that arent stopping?) and or anything else pending like web updates

Comment: How do you reopen the app? Maybe that takes 5 seconds instead of terminating the app.

Comment: i call to StopAllCoroutines(); so all the routines will be stop?,No i dont use web updates

Answer (score 0):

If you are quitting the game.
By default, Unity writes preferences to disk during `OnApplicationQuit()`.
So there is no need for `PlayerPrefs.Save();`There is no need to call `StopAllCoroutines();`either as `Application.Quit();` shut the running application down. So, please comment out this two-line first then see the result.

Comment: Same errors, i used this 2 lines to help in the error but don't work